# Fields are required after submit

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to indicate that fields are required after the application form I am currently working on has submitted, currently I am able to display a list of the fields that are missing at the top of the screen as shown below:

[image]

These error messages are currently being sent back from a web api and then being added to the ModelState through the AddModelErrors method the code I am using to do this is shown below:

```
if (model.ApplicationValidations != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.ApplicationValidations.Select((validationMessage) => new {validationMessage}))
            {
                if (item.validationMessage.URL == "Apply Personal Details")
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("required fields", item.validationMessage.FieldName + " is required");
                }
            }
        }
```

On similar forms I have worked on required fields will initially have a red asterix next to them:

[image]

When the form is submitted those field not containing data or where the data is in an incorrect format will be highlighted pink as shown below:

[image]

I need the field highlighting only to show when the Model Errors are being shown, currently the form saves the data as the user moves to the next section, validation is not needed when this happens only when the form is finally submitted should the highlighting be shown.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I could implement this?

Thanks in advance for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript to call the HTML5 "setCustomValidity()" on the DOM element on the basis of the returned error data from the web API call. See this article on [HTML5 constraint validation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) for more information on the HTML5 validation.

To support older browsers you can look at a polyfill such as [HF5](https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F).